# Golang Unmarshalling behaviour: Excess fields?

Tags: json, rest, go, unmarshalling

Suppose I have this struct:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
}
```

But I receive a response of the form:

```
{"a": "something", "b": "something", "c": "something"}
```

i.e. There are more fields than expected, but we only want the field A. Is it safe/allowed in golang to unmarshal the response into MyStruct?

Comment: Yes, `b` and `c` are ignored.

Comment: As already pointed out by others it is safe, the extra fields will simply be ignored. If you want however, you can make the unmarshaling process to fail with an error if the input contains more fields than you expect; if that's something you'd want to do, see: [`DisallowUnknownFields`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.19.5#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe, and even used sometimes intentionally. If you need only a few fields from an input, you can define a structure that includes only those fields. In fact, it is harder to detect if there are fields in the input that are left unmarshaled.